# How to patch java file with gradle?

Tags: gradle

I can't patch file with gradle. I try to use ant by always got an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':rbps-api:compileJava'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "patch" (in directory "C:\Users\IdeaProjects\cosmos\rbps-api"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

gradle debug:

```
11:31:46.535 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:31:46.536 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:31:46.536 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
11:31:46.536 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Users\oleh.havryliv\IdeaProjects\cosmos\rbps-api\build.gradle' line: 56
11:31:46.536 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:31:46.536 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:31:46.537 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':rbps-api:assemble'.
11:31:46.537 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "patch" (in directory "C:\Users\oleh.havryliv\IdeaProjects\cosmos\rbps-api"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
11:31:46.537 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:31:46.537 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
11:31:46.538 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
11:31:46.538 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:31:46.538 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
11:31:46.538 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
11:31:46.539 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

gradle.xml

```
apply plugin: 'java'

    compileJava.doLast {
            ant.patch(patchfile: "$rootDir\\rbps-api\\ResourceBundle.patch" , originalFile: "$rootDir\\rbps-api\\src\\main\\java\\com\\medtronic\\diabetes\\carelink\\rbps\\api\\resource\\ResourceBundle.java")
        }
```

Files exist on these paths.  What could be wrong? Maybe exist another approach?

Comment: I think the error is saying gradle could not find the `patch` executable. It is not in your PATH at the time gradle wants to execute it. You might get more detail if you specify the --debug flag on the gradle command line.

Comment: @Jeff Holt, debug didn't helped

Comment: Show the value of the PATH environment variable and then show all occurrences of PATCH.EXE on every disk mounted.

Comment: Do I need manually install patch?  I thought gradle had patch under the hood...

Comment: Yes. Neither gradle nor ant come with patch. But ant does have a task definition that lets you execute patch if you have patch installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff Holt has already mentioned in the comments: the `patch` Ant task ”requires `patch` to be on the execution path” (cf. [Ant docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/patch.html)).